# Error when trigger click event in IE6/IE7 (jquery)

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#boxId ul li a:eq(0)").click();
```

Works ok in IE8 and FF, but I'm getting error in IE6 and IE7.

```
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

Someone knows why?

Obs:

```
$("#boxFoto ul li a:eq(0)").size(); // returns '1'
```

Comment: Did you define a click function? Seems you are calling .click() without having it binded?

Comment: Can you also show us your HTML?

Comment: try: $("#boxId ul li a:).get(0).click();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error.

My code creates HTML dinamically, using this:

```
a.setAttribute("onclick","return false");
```

I changed to

```
a.onclick = function(){return false;};
```

And now works!

---

IE6/IE7 were returning the string "return false" in jquery code, not the function(){return false}. Somewhere in jquery code, I was getting "return false".apply(....., .....), that was the cause of the error `Object doesn't support this property or method`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason for jQuery's [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to fail on IE. I think the `click` event is actually triggered, but:

- You have set an `onclick` handler on the hyperlink, and it tries to access a property or a method that's undefined under IE, or
- You have an `href="javascript:....."` attribute on the hyperlink that has the same problem as above.